# Solve $y'' - y' = yy'$ and find three Other Distinct Solutions

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Been stuck on this for a while. I need to solve the following differential equation by **finding the constant solution y = c** **and** **three other distinct solutions.**

$$y'' - y' = yy'$$

If someone could give me a complete step by step explanation, it would be greatly appreciated as I want to fully understand it.

Comment: @Amzoti yes it is. The ['] represent derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going from JJacquelin's answer, the equation can be written as

$$ \frac{2 \,dy}{y^2 + 2y + C} = dx$$

For $C = 1$

$$ \int \frac{2\,dy}{(y+1)^2} = \int dx $$
$$ -\frac{2}{y+1} = x + C_1 $$
$$ y = -1 - \frac{2}{x + c}$$

For $C < 1$

$$\int \frac{2\,dy}{(y-C_1)(y-C_2)} = \int dx $$
$$ \frac{2}{C_2-C_1}\ln \frac{y-C_2}{y-C_1} = x + C_3$$
$$ y = 2 \frac{c_2 - c_1 c_3 e^{(c_2-c_1)x}}{1 - c_3 e^{(c_2-c_1)x}}$$

For $C > 1$

$$ \int \frac{2\,dy}{(y+1)^2 + C_1^2} = \int dx $$
$$ \frac{2}{C_1} \arctan \frac{y+1}{C_1} = x + C_2 $$
$$ y = -1 + 2c_1\tan (c_1 x + c_2)$$

Answer (score 3):

Another method, through direct integration  of $y''-y'=yy'$
$$y'-y=\frac{1}{2}y^2+C$$
This is a separable ODE:  $\frac{dy}{y+\frac{1}{2}y^2+C}=dx$
$$2C_1\tan^{-1}(C_1(y+1))=x+C_2$$
$$y=2c_1\tan\big(c_1x+c_2\big)-1$$
Particular solutions are obtained with various values of $c_1$ and $c_2$. For example :

$c_1=0$ gives $y=$constant=$c$

$c_1=1$ and $c_2=0$ gives $y=2\tan(x)-1$

etc. You can obtain as many patricular solutions as you want.

Also one can observe that changing $c_2$ to $c_2+\pi/2$ changes the tan to -cot. So the solutions can also be expressed on the form (with different $c_2$) :
$$y=-2c_1 \cot\big(c_1x+c_2\big)-1$$

Moreover, the solutions are not limited to real $c_1 , c_2$, but can be imaginary numbers, for example changing $c_1$ to $ic_1$ changes $c_1\tan(c_1x)$ to $-c_1\tanh(c_1x)$. So, the solutions can also be expressed on the form :
$$y=-2c_1\tanh\big(c_1x+c_2\big)-1$$
or
$$y=2c_1 \coth\big(c_1x+c_2\big)-1$$

Comment: Still a little confused as to how I would find 3 other distinct solutions..

Comment: See the addition at end of my answer.

Comment: So when I'm trying to find the other distinct solutions, can I choose the c1 and c2 to be whatever I want?

Comment: Yes !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Also, see at the end of my main answer that equivalent forms of solutions can be expressed with -2cotan, -2tanh and 2cotanh instead of 2tan only. May be it's what was expected as full answer.

Comment: Look at my answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: The solution given by Dylan on Nov 5 at 22:36 is the same than the solution I gave on Nov 4 at 7:33 . But it  must be completed by adding the solutions in terms of cot, tanh and coth, instead of tan only, as explained in my answer on Nov.5 at 2:40

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the independent variable is $x$, you can make the necessary changes if it's $t$ or anything else.

Let $z=y'$.  Then
$$y''=\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=z\frac{dz}{dy}$$
and substituting into the DE gives
$$z\frac{dz}{dy}-z=yz\ .$$
See if you can take it from here.