# General solution including tanh

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling with solving this ODE:
$$
f''+ff'=0, f(0)=0
$$
I am thinking rewriting the second term as $\frac{1}{2}(f^2)'$, so that the ODE can be
$$
f''+\frac{1}{2}(f^2)'=0
$$
then integrating it, I can get
$$
f'+\frac{1}{2}f^2=A
$$

However, I cannot process it. The general solution is a $tanh$ function. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use seperation of variables.

Comment: You provide an initial condition but your ODE is of a second-order type. Is there any other initial condition regarding $f'$?

Comment: Saddly, $f(0)=0$ is the only condition.

Comment: Separation of variables sounds good, it reminds me when I solve PDE. But how to use it for ODE?

Comment: Duplicates and nearly so: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957967/is-fx-2-xc-the-only-solution-to-f-ff, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005326/solve-y-y-yy-and-find-three-other-distinct-solutions, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501684/how-to-solve-a-non-linear-equation, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784007/find-a-solution-for-y-in-a-nonlinear-second-order-differential-equation-missi

Answer (score 1):

This now has the form of a Riccati equation. Set $f=2\frac{g'}{g}$ to get
$$
2g''=Ag.
$$
This is now a linear DE with constant coefficients, the cases $A>0$, $A=0$, $A<0$ naturally lead to well-known solution classes.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's amazing!